# Tricky CSS vertical centering with padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two columns of dynamic content, and want to align them as follows:

a) if the right column is small, I want it to be vertically centered

b) if the right column is large, I want it to be top aligned

c) the right column should always have (at least) 80px top padding.

See first and second image below for desired behavior.

Without c), this is trivial, eg one method is using flex with the second column having align-self:flex-start .

With c) it still appears trivial - just give the right column 80px top AND bottom padding to ensure it is centered, but extends down if it doesn't fit.

However, I do not want the extra 80px at the bottom when the content is large, as shown in the third image below, which makes things far more complex. I've tried a solution like having the right column its own flex container with flex-direction:column, using two 80px height divs with one set to flex-shrink:1 and the main content set to flex-shrink:0, in the hope that one 80px would collapse when unnecessary - but this simply doesn't work (the right column isn't restricted in height so never shrinks).

Any options? The use-case here is that the right column is dynamic text, but the obvious option of having 80px top and bottom results in either too large a gap to the next section of content when the text is long, or too short a gap if the text is short.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a snippet?

Comment: Well, there's one option I don't know much about flexbox but grid is great to use. Try that.